# Assert duration of an entire test plan in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, integration-testing

I've got a test plan that I want to assert the duration of the entire run, not an individual request or sampler, but the whole run.

I've got an integration test where I want to make sure it completes in a certain amount of time, else fail the test. The test itself consists of one initial HTTP request, followed by a While controller making follow up HTTP requests until a condition is satisfied. The broader use case is effectively testing an [Asynchronous HTTP API](http://restcookbook.com/Resources/asynchroneous-operations/).

Thus far all docs on the Duration Assertion seem to apply it only to a sampler, and I've tried adding it at the Thread Group and at the Test Plan level but it doesn't appear to have any effect.